# Merging two pages into one homepage

Tags: homepage, merging

I am trying to customise my Wordpress homepage.

I decided to get fullscreen image theme (TwoFold by Fuel Themes). 
As I am preparing photography portfolio website, graphic content is very important to me. 
However, I'd like to add some text below the image slider, ideally it would be a whole page below the current homepage slider. 
Please see the demo theme: [TwoFold Theme](http://twofold.fuelthemes.net)

And what I would like to add (simple mockup):

[image: Desired layout]

Methods I found here seem not to work well - they extend bottom of the homepage, however return no content below the slider.

Let's say I'd like to insert "About" page under the slider. How should I modify home page layout to do that?

Orignal code below:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php 
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $home_layout = get_post_meta($id, 'home_layout', true) ? get_post_meta($id, 'home_layout', true) : 'style1';
    get_template_part( 'inc/templates/homepage/'.$home_layout );
?>
<?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Lots of thanks for any hints as I am clueless.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add a div with some dummy content right after your `endif` and above `get_footer()`. If you do not see the content, inspect it with developer tools and determine what CSS you may need to adjust.

Comment: Open this file: `inc/templates/homepage/`. Add your content there.

Answer (score 1):

Your theme is dynamically loading a template part.

Look here:

```
   $home_layout = get_post_meta($id, 'home_layout', true) ? get_post_meta($id,'home_layout', true) : 'style1';
get_template_part( 'inc/templates/homepage/'.$home_layout );
```

Now look in your folder at `inc/templates/homepage/` and you should see the various template parts.

Those templates parts are where you'll want to add your new code (for the about page).

Comment: Thanks Tim and WebElaine! It worked. I added <div> with <object> to the ../homepage/style1.php. It looks great, however I wanted to SEO optimise that added content. Google crawler seem to skip that part. Is that any way to improve that?

Comment: Give Yoast SEO a look maybe

Comment: Yoast SEO won't read the content neither in <object> nor in <iframe>...

Answer (score 1):

It worked almost as I wanted, thank you for the comments!

Almost - therefore I have one more question. (I am sorry if that is obvious, I am not experienced and I am learning everything just now, I already learnt a lot and I want to learn more as currently I cannot afford paying for these modifications).

I tried two method:

**Method 1 - inserting separate (non-WP) page in *div* and *iframe*** into style1.php - it looks exactly as I wanted:

### [image]

However **returned content is not seen by** Google bot, not seen by WP Admin and WP Plugins, which makes all very difficult to optimise.

**Method 2 - echoing other WP page with desired content by:**

```
<?php
$your_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=about' );
while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

What returned raw text:

### [image]

**which is visible for** Google bot, WP engine etc.

**My question is:
How do I return formatted page that is visible for Google, WP, plugins etc.?**

I know that it may be simple, however I achieved a lot already and I'd like to finalise whole project with your help and my good will.

Many thanks!